# How to stop .htaccess redirect from .html file to a .php file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a number of sites on a "deluxe hosting" plan on GoDaddy, which means there is one top-level site at the root, and for each additional domain, their files reside in a folder within the root. If you think this question has been asked before, then please direct me to the solution, because I can't find quite the answer, though I'm sure it isn't new.

Now, there is an .htaccess file in the root (the top-level site), which is used to redirect in the case where someone types in "index.html" it goes to "index.php":

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

redirect 301 /about.html /about.php
redirect 301 /boat.html /boat.php
redirect 301 /contact.html /contact.php
redirect 301 /charters.html /index.php
redirect 301 /combotrips.html /index.php
redirect 301 /contact-thanks.html /contact-thanks.php
redirect 301 /crew.html /crew.php
redirect 301 /diving.html /key-west-diving.php
redirect 301 /divingcharters.html /key-west-diving.php
redirect 301 /ecocharters.html /eco-tours.php
redirect 301 /fishingcharters.html /key-west-fishing.php
redirect 301 /gallery.html /gallery.php
redirect 301 /index.html /index.php
redirect 301 /packnship.html /key-west-fish-shipped.php
redirect 301 /testimonials.html /testimonials.php
redirect 301 /thefish.html /key-west-fishing.php
redirect 301 /fishing-charters.php /fishing-charter-rates.php


#redirect 301 /Fish%20Availability%20Chart.pdf /docs/key-west-local-fish.pdf
```

I did not write the .htaccess file. In fact, I don't really understand .htaccess files all that well.

Now I added a new site, which has its sub-folder. This new site was moved from another completely different hosting company. This new site has an index.html, about.html, etc. When I type in "index.html, it immediately tries to redirect to index.php. Same thing with about.php, and I think all the other .html pages try to redirect to a .php page.

In this new site folder, there is no .htaccess file.

I did write a new .htaccess file, and put a RewriteEngine Off line, but it didn't do anything different.

How can I make this site not redirect the .html files to .php files?

**Update:**
To get this working I gutted all but the first and last lines of the top-level .htaccess file contents. I don't count this as *the* answer but more like "a solution". I'm not really sure why the top-level site has those redirects to begin with. I inherited this site from a previous web company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need a `.htaccess` file. An `.htaccess` file is simply for overwriting the server's `httpd.conf` file at a user-controllable and restricted level without allowing the user full control of the server's config file. If you're not using it for anything you can delete it.

Because you had 301 redirects in your `.htaccess` file before they're likely cached by your browser (even though you deleted them from the `.htaccess` file).

To disable a rule you can add a `#` comment tag in front of it.

Additionally you can delete the rule.

Until the redirect rules are removed, the server would send the header request for the redirect. Once it's been removed (but it's in your cache) you will need to delete your browser's cache to make the redirect stop happening.

You can keep the .htaccess file for the rewriting of the 404 error handler though.

Comment: Thanks! The browser caching was the most aggravating, because I couldn't tell what was working and what wasn't working. I had to try the site in three different browsers to see that deleting the redirect lines did work. Now, I think it's all working.